# Local python module overrides module installed with pip

Tags: django, python-2.7, import, pip, python-module

I am having issues with importing, my own, pip package named the same as a module inside a django-app. Lets say my own pip module is called: `fancymodule`. I then have a module-folder inside a django-app named the same:

```
* django-project
    * payments
        * models.py
        * fancymodule/
            * __init__.py
```

The problem I am having, is that inside `payments/models.py`, I import:

```
from fancymodule import ApiClient
```

This is suppose to reference the `fancymodule` installed through pip. But is instead referencing the module inside the payments-django-app instead.

If I wanted to reference the module inside the payments-django-app, in my head, this should be:

```
from payments.fancymodule import whatever
```

I get that from the view of `payments/models.py`, the `import fancymodule ..` will reference `fancymodule` inside the payments-folder.. but can i change/fix this, so it reference the `fancymodule` installed through pip ?

FYI: Working on an old legacy project.

Home someone can help.

Comment: Why does your PYTHONPATH have the path to the django (django-project/payments) app in it? Remove that and you're golden.

Comment: are you using VS code? if so there should be a settings.json file in a .vscode folder where you can modify that easily.

Comment: hmmm Melvyn, that is a good question.. its a old project i didn't start, so might be the place i need to look into.. ill come back with what i find :)

I am using pycharm, so no vscode stuff.

Comment: For Python 2.x importing `fancymodule` from `payments/models.py` would import `payments.fancymodule`. To avoid that you should add `from __future__ import absolute_import` (see PEP328, py2.5+) at the top of the `models.py` (beware that other imports may fail). For Python 3.x the issue may be related to PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**marcinn** suggestion about using `from __future__ import absolute_import` worked.

So my solution inside the `models.py` file ended up being:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from fancymodule import ApiClient
```

And as I said to above comment.. I couldn't find anything wrong with my PYTHONPATH. as marcinn also said, this is most likly a Python 3.x thing.. and since i am on 2.7, it makes sense the PYTHONPATH looks fine.

OBS: PyCharm redlines the `from fancymodule import ApiClient`, but it works. So i think its just PyCharm that needs to be restartet to remove the redlines.